# Accessibility service don't call onKeyEvent in games & jetpack Compose

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-jetpack-compose, accessibility, accessibilityservice

### How to know if user interacts with screen when my app is in background?

I need to check is **user is performing any touches** or gestures on display while my application is in the background and in the foreground is any game or app.

---

I thought I can do it by my own `AccessibilityService` for this purpose and every time when user touch the screen, or make a swipe gesture, or whatever - I will catch callback by `onKeyEvent()`, `onAccessibilityEvent()` or `onGesture()`. That will be perfect because from `event` I also know by which application was the event invoked.

However from my testing it looks like `AccessibilityService` callbacks do not work in apps written in Jetpack Compose nor any games which are probably written in Unity.

---

Is there any solution please? I will be thankful also for completely different solution than using Accessibility service if it will fulfil my requierements.